how to smooth these parts of the material?
I am stuggling, this part of my 3d model is having trouble beiing smooth. Am I missing something? I have already done a shade smooth, recalculate normals, and checked orientation faces.  what am I doing wrong? any ideas for me?



Hello, try to go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data, if it doesn't work please share your file

Seems like a model imported from some CAD software. It could be that it's made out of unconnected parts, you could try merging by distance, but it also sometimes happens that it's not possible as sometimes solid models might get converted to surfaces that do not necessarily have vertices in the same places. In that case there is not much that can be done easily and it might be easier to just remodel the whole thing making sure it has proper topology. ...or try to re-export it from whatever CAD software it comes from with different settings, but that might not always be possible.

@moonboots YES! that solved it THANKS!

Here are 2 things that you can try that might help,

Clear Custom Split Normals Data, 

then use Weigheted Normals Modifier, 


